images and css not loaded in firefox when using localhost
I have a question regarding why image and css styles not loaded in my html webpage when trying to run in FireFox using localhost.


p.hometown {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: green;
}

h4 {
    background-color:blue;
}

h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#para1{
    color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}


k.center{
    color: green;
    text-align: right;
}


#geeks {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: skyblue;
}
This is HTML here!


<p class="hometown">
    Another line here!
</p>

<img src="check.png" alt="an image here" width="100" height="88">

<p id="para1">
    Should be in Yellow color this line.
</p>

<h1 style ="color:blue"> A simple Chat Application</h1>
<h2> a h2 here </h2>
<p> a new paragraph!</p>



Here is the Output of the Console output from Web Developer in Firefox (as you can see the image is not displayed and none of the two CSS elements that I used were displayed):
enter image description here
also here is the stylesheet in FireFox web developer tool:
enter image description here
Could someone tells me where could have gone wrong so that none of the css styles were displayed and also the image was not display? I have tested my code in Visual Studio Code using Live Server and was able to display them properly as shown here:
enter image description here
but the image and the CSS were not displayed or rendered at all in Firefox when I used localhost to run the html.
I have tried running my codes in Live Server and it worked. But the html was not displayed properly in Firefox.
Also my css file with line number here:
enter image description here

You css file should be in the same folder with your HTML file. Also check thé name should be exactly thé same

Does it work in any other browser? Almost certainly a path issue otherwise.

The code you have given works fine for me (FF on Windows10) so I can't help as there appears to be no problem. What debugging have you tried? For example, the errors include that you are in quirks mode, but the code you have given us isn't. Also it's showing a problem at line 28 in the CSS file - that is associated with the tag k being used as a selector. Have you tried removing that and seeing what happens? And what is tag k, it isn't a standard HTML tag and it isn't in the HTML you have given us.

@AHaworth Hi could you point out how to tell if "tag k" is being used by looking at line 28? because I tried looking at line 28 of the css file, but somehow it is the line "font-size: 25px". I see in the output here https://i.sstatic.net/TOQAyVJj.png, it says "Ruleset ignored due to bad selector" for line 28:8 in myCustomStyle.css file. But line 28 has the "font-size: 25px" there, so I am not sure why "font-size: 25px" is causing the problem? could you explain little more. thanks a lot.

@Paulie_D Hi, I have uploaded a screenshot of the html file with the path that I used there, could you have  look to see if my path is correct?  thanks. Or if you could spot anything else that might cause the error?
